# Filter input render bug in React-Table with expanded

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have some troube to understand the behavior I observe.
I use pivot and filter function with React-Table (v6), and I want to expand my row when the filter match with a subrow value.

I achieved the expand of the row but when I entered a value  (in a input filter) present in subrow the input filter is not changed (like rerender to empty) ...
It's look like the setState reset the input field.
The state.expended is an object which contains index with a boolean to specify if the row is expanded or not.

I upload a sample of my problem of codesanbox here, I reproduce the [problem:codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-table-pivoting-expanded-cjrsy)

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem when, after using the filter, the extensions began to work incorrectly. Perhaps a subrow will help you:

```
getSubRows: (row) => row.subRows

useTable(
   {
      columns: columns,
      data: data,
      defaultColumn: {
         Filter: ''
      },
      initialState: {},
      getSubRows: (row) => row.subRows
   },
   useExpanded,
   useFilters
);
```